# Gurobi:Python:How to use abs() function with decision variables

Tags: python, typeerror, mathematical-optimization, gurobi

I am trying to use abs function with decision variables but Gurobi gives this output :

```
TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'gurobipy.LinExpr'
```

Here the code that gurobi directs me for the error;

```
PPP = quicksum((1 / (1+AAA)**y)*abs(W2G[p]+S2G[p]-EPD[p])*BBB*CCC
      for y in range(1,DDD+1) for p in range(1,EEE+1))
```

**`W2G` and `S2G` are decision variables while `EPD` is a parameter.

I tried Numpy.absolute to solve the problem but it seems Gurobi does not like to process abs function in loops constructed with decision variables.

I would be happy if anyone has an idea?

Thanks,
Enes

Comment: From [Gurobi's web page](http://www.gurobi.com/support/faqs): "Gurobi has no dedicated interface to model piecewise linear expressions, but these can be solved easily via special ordered sets of type 2 (SOS-2)." You can linearize the absolute value of the decision variable

Comment: @cricked_007 Thank you for your answer, I ll try to model in that way.

Comment: were you able to solve this @enkey?